# Error in comparing of two arrays: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, numpy-slicing

I have an array `a` with the shape of `(1000000,32)` and array `b` with the shape of `(10000,32)`

I want to find the indices of a that contains the rows of b.
I have written the following code:

```
I = np.argwhere((a == b[:, None]).all(axis=2))[:, 1]
```

when I test it in other cases it works very well. But for my current arrays it gives the following error:

```
...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:111: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Any idea what is the source of the error? thanks

Comment: `a == b[:, None]` with the shapes you list should be `(10000,1000000,32)`.  But if there's a mismatch in shapes (that can't be broadcast properly) the result will be the warning and a `False` value.  Obviously you can't use `all` on that `False`.  Check and double check the shapes.  If necessary look at the `==` result by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
result = (a[:, np.newaxis] == b).all(-1).any(-1)
```

Steps:

- `a[:, np.newaxis] == b` - "by element" comparison. First and second index -
  indices of rows from *a* and *b*, third index - column index in both rows.
- `….all(-1)` - does *a[i]* has its "counterpart" in *b[j]* (**all**
  elements of both rows are equal).
- `….any(-1)` - does *a[i]* has its "counterpart" in **any** row in *b*.

To check the results of each step, use 2 arrays with e.g. up to 10 rows and
2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.arange(a.shape[0])[np.isin(a,b).all(axis=1)]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.arange(60).reshape(10,6)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
   [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
   [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
   [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
   [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
   [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
   [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])
>>> b=np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
   [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> np.arange(a.shape[0])[np.isin(a,b).all(axis=1)]
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Of course `np.isin()` is in the docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and tests if an element of `a` is in `b`. The questioner is already familiar with `all()` and the use of the `axis=1` argument. So `np.isin(a,b).all(axis=1)` produces a boolean array that selects from among the indexes of `a` which are represented by `np.arange(a.shape[0])`.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.